# How to add sound applet to "taskbar" in gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, indicator-sound

does anyone here knows how to add a sound applet or volume control to the taskbar or gnome 3? In order to mute, I'm using maverick

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have the same touble I have.
When the sound applet/volume control vanish I open a terminal and run:

```
pulseaudio
```

if doesn't work, try:

```
killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio
```

try it to see if works.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean by taskbar. There are many to choose from. I'll assume that you're using Gnome Panel (also known as Gnome Classic and recently Gnome Fallback). In that case, you can install the [indicator-applet](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-applet) package. You can then press and hold alt, right-click the panel and choose "add to panel". This will bring up a list of applets that you can choose from. Press alt and middel-click to drag applets where you want them. In 11.10 and newer, this package isn't in the official repositories, but you can add them from here: https://launchpad.net/indicator-applet

While the previous applies only to Gnome Panel, indicator support is available for both Xfce4-panel and Lxpanel (from LXDE). Both can easily be used on Gnome 3 and both can be run simultaneous with Unity if you want to.